# Comparing two values in same mongodb document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to figure out how to compare the currentBid with the reserve price. If a user's bid is not higher than the reserve price, then I want to filter out that document or if the the reserve price value is `None`, then don't filter the document in the GET request. 
The expression used is something I was looking at in a stack post, but never got working. How can I compare two values within same document?

model definition

```
  reservePrice: { type: String },
  currentBid: { type: String }
```

```
      Post.find({
      $expr: {
        $or: [
          {
            $and: [
              { $in: ["$bidderId", req.query.bidderId] },
              { $lte: ["$auctionEndDateTime", Date.now()] },
              { $gt: ["$reservePrice", "$currentBid"] }
            ],
            $and: [
              { $in: ["$bidderId", req.query.bidderId] },
              { $lte: ["$auctionEndDateTime", Date.now()] },
              { $ne: ["$reservePrice", "None"] }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    })
      .populate("creator", "username")
      .then(documents => {
        console.log(documents);
        req.params.Id = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.Id);
        res.status(200).json({
          message: "Auction listings retrieved successfully!",
          posts: documents
        });
      });
```